# Use IF to identify what inner join should i used

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like this

```
Select Name, Identifier, ReferenceId, ReferenceAccountId
FROM Test
```

And before I start the inner join, I Have a field named `Identifier`.
If This is 1 then I will use the inner join `ref_reference1` else I will use the other one.

```
INNER JOIN Ref_Reference1 ON Ref_Reference1.ReferenceId = Test.ReferenceId
INNER JOIN Ref_Reference2 ON Ref_Reference2.ReferenceId = Test.ReferenceId
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. You cannot change the "shape" of the query without using dynamic SQL, and you should generally avoid that where possible.

Instead, you can do two left joins:

```
LEFT JOIN Ref_Reference1 ON
     Ref_Reference1.ReferenceId = Test.ReferenceId
     AND Test.Identifier = 1
LEFT JOIN Ref_Reference2 ON
     Ref_Reference2.ReferenceId = Test.ReferenceId
     AND Test.Identifier <> 1
```

You'll notice that you now also have a strong benefit - you can *reference* these tables elsewhere in your query (how were you planning to deal with that in your proposal?)

Answer (score 3):

You can try 2 left joins with condition and check

```
Select 
    Name, Identifier, ReferenceId, ReferenceAccountId,
    ISNULL(Ref_Reference1.ReferenceId,Ref_Reference2.ReferenceId)
FROM Test
LEFT OUTER JOIN Ref_Reference1 ON Ref_Reference1.ReferenceId = Test.ReferenceId AND Identifier = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Ref_Reference2 ON Ref_Reference2.ReferenceId = Test.ReferenceId AND Identifier <> 1
```

Comment: in this answer i've used the ISNULL . . . and supply it to the asnwer of Damien. then my query works good. thanks to your effort. god bless sir :)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in the language that allows it as I think you want. However, if the structure of the two results comes out the same, you can store off intermediate results;

```
if ...
  select ...
  into #result
  from ... join reference1 
else
  select ...
  into #result
  from ... join reference2
```

but it's not nice...